# Fixing 'PATH' in Environment Variables in Windows 7 for multiple applications

Tags: java, ruby, windows, environment-variables

After using JDK if I use ruby, I have to change 'PATH' in Environment Variables in Windows7. Is there a work around where I don't have to keep changing it even if I use multiple applications?

Comment: This question is too broad. Tell us more about what you are experiencing and why you have to change your PATH variable

Comment: The Path variable in the Environment Variables will be different for ruby and java since java.exe and ruby.exe are in different locations. Now lets say I just finished working with jdk and now I wish to work on ruby. When I type ruby -v before setting Path to location of ruby.exe it gives me the following erroe: 'ruby' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: There is no reason you can't have java/bin and ruby/bin in your PATH at the same time.

Comment: That's exactly my question. How can I asssign two or more different locations to Path?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Separate the paths to Ruby and Java with your system's path separator character.

In case of Windows 7, it's

```
;
```

You'll be able to use both

Here's an example of Path variable with numerous applications.

```
C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\
```

Comment: Great. Thanks for the answer.