# Multiple Applications in PATH variable

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am working through a Rails tutorial that requires creating a database in MySQL. From the command prompt, I am unable to access both Rails and MySQL within the same session. I'm having to complete steps in one program, then change the path, restart the computer, and continue in the other application.

I've found a solution that worked for others at:
 [Fixing 'PATH' in Environment Variables in Windows 7 for multiple applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801662/fixing-path-in-environment-variables-in-windows-7-for-multiple-applications)

This has led me to try this path:

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin; C:\Ruby23-x64\bin; C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin

For some reason, it's not working for me. My laptop seems only to recognize the first application mentioned in my PATH variable. If I put the MySQL part first, then Command Prompt doesn't recognize Rails, and vice-versa.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you have spaces after the colon ; ?

Comment: Yes. Should there be no spaces?

Comment: Removing the spaces fixed the problem. If you'd like to change your comment to an answer, I'll mark it as fixed! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant have spaces between each path like:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin; C:\Ruby23-x64\bin; C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin
```

**remove spaces**

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin;C:\Ruby23-x64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin
```